# Feedback.js not showing sreenshot

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am trying to add Feedback.js (which is enhancement to html2canvas.js) to our website.

So far I was able to add Send Feedback button to the page and onclick it asks user to fill a feedback textbox. But in the examples I have seen on the Feedback.js website after clicking continue there is an option to choose Highlight or Blackout dom elements. But when I click on the Continue Button after I fill the reason, it only shows loading Gif like it only wants to send the data but not to choose screenshot. Am I missing some option ?

Code here:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="src/feedback.js/feedback.js"></script>
<link href="src/feedback.js/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){   
    Feedback({
        h2cPath: "src/feedback.js/html2canvas.js"
    });
  });    
</script>
```

Just this loading gif appears on the page.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your console? Maybe there's some info we can use. 'Feedback.js' is ambiguous by the way, there are multiple libraries with the same name. Which one are you using? I want to use a similar tool, but they all have serious quality issues. niklasvh/feedback.js has many stars but inactive for 7 years, ivoviz/feedback inactive for 1.5 year.